# Why does the value of angle(0) is chosen 0 in matlab? I expect it as NaN.

Tags: matlab

angle(z) represents argument of the complex number z. Then what is angle(0)? Again, if it represents the principal argument, then why does the -pi value also appear in some cases, when you are dealing with decimals?

Comment: `angle` is implemented with `atan2`. You can read about the practical reasons why `0` is chosen as the otherwise undefined result of `angle(0)` (`atan2(0,0)`) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, [it is indeed undefined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626392/what-is-the-argument-of-0) as the value of the limit depends on how the two function's arguments approach their zero values.  That's all fine and good for analysis.

However, from a numeric, programming perspective, it may be very annoying to have a `NaN` or exception throw for such a generate case.  [Here's a nice little blog post](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/09/180741.html) going over some short history of defining the behavior. As such, and since Mathworks [doesn't give a reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#buct8h0-4), I'd imagine they are using some implementation of the [C99 standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2) (though [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#r6) gives a better breakdown) for programmatically defining the mathematically undefined values along certain paths for robustness's sake:

```
>> x = [0 , 0-eps(0) , 0+eps(0) , 0-eps(0) , 0+eps(0) , 0-eps(0)];
>> y = [0 , 0        , 0+eps(0) , 0-eps(0) , 0-eps(0) , 0+eps(0)];
>> atan2(y,x)
ans =
         0    3.1416    0.7854   -2.3562   -0.7854    2.3562
```

(As far as I know, Matlab doesn't have a concise way to "sign" zeros, so I deferred to the smallest possible floating points, which are still technically finite.)

Comment: Matlab does sign zeroes, it's only that it doesn't show the sign. Compare `typecast(0,'uint8')` and `typecast(-0,'uint8')`

Comment: @LuisMendo Interesting that it has the distinction but `0` and `-0` as doubles are treated equivalently in this application.